android Start an activity from foreground service
public class LockScreenService extends Service {

    public static final int LOCK_SCREEN_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = -10;
    private BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        localeSet(this);
        startForeground(LOCK_SCREEN_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, createServiceNotification());

        screenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "screen on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

        registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (screenOnReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(screenOnReceiver);
            screenOnReceiver = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    private Notification createServiceNotification() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class); // activity you wanna show when the notification is clicked
        int flags = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent, flags);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getResources().getString(R.string.service_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.service_notification_title))
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.service_notification_content))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        return builder.build();

    }


    private void localeSet(Context context) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String langCode = prefs.getString("languageCode", "");

        Locale locale = new Locale(langCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);

        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


Hi! I am a newbie programmer and there are so many things to learn.
I'm trying to make an android app, which is todolist app that shows a user todolist on lock screen.
I made a foreground service that has a broadcast receiver instance as a field, and the broadcast receiver listen to 'screen-on' action so when the user turn on screen the app shows a user an activity. as you can see in the code above, for now, when the screen is turned on, the app shows you toast 'screen on!' and it seems to be working fine.
        screenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(intent.getAction())) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "screen on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    // Intent to launch the desired activity
                    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
//
//                    // Include these flags to launch the activity even if the device is locked
                    activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//
//                    // Starting the activity
                    startActivity(activityIntent);
                }
            }
        };

and then i changed broadcast receiver code this way, and it kinda opened an activity on lock screen. but when i turned off the app, even though the foreground service is alive, the app didn't open an activity. it only shows you 'screen on!' toast. what should i do to popup activity from service even if the app is turned off?
i've been looking up for this but they were no recent information about this.
i also read
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts
and i made the app ask SYSTEN_ALERT_WINDOW permission to user, but even with the permission the app didnt show an activitiy on lock screen when the app is turned off.
※ sorry for my english, im not a native english speaker.

That's the wrong permission, you'd need:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

An Activity will never show on the lock-screen, only the Notification which leads to it. Which I think it's also impossible to show any Toast with the lock-screen active; that BroadcastReceiver is useless.
When wanting to show more details, you should add:
 .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

A custom layout for the notification might permit to display even more info.

ah, i added the alert thingy permission because in the document it said the app need that permission to start an activity from background.  in manifest.xml i did     and i also did       

hummm but i found some todolist app that shows a todolist on lock screen. maybe there weren't an activity. i guess i will also try to show user todolist with sth else like notification.  i appreciate your help :))

This may be a custom notification-layout; otherwise this is a very basic layout. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification
